# PHP 5.3.10: var_dump does not print readable results as it used to be

Tags: php-5.3, var-dump

After I have upgraded my localhost **wamp server** to php **5.3.10**, the `var_dump` does not print results that are as readable/pretty as they used to be.

```
$obj = (object) array('qualitypoint', 'technologies', 'India');
var_dump($obj);

object(stdClass)#2 (3) { [0]=> string(12) "qualitypoint" [1]=> string(12) "technologies" [2]=> string(5) "India" }
```

As you can see that everything now is cramp into one line.

It used to print something like this below though,

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
 [0]=> string(12) "qualitypoint"
 [1]=> string(12) "technologies"
 [2]=> string(5) "India"
}
```

How can I make var_dump to return a readable formatted result?

Comment: Print a `<pre>` before? Or set content-type to `text/plain`.

Comment: print_r(var_dump($var));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object(stdClass)#2 (3) { [0]=> string(12) "qualitypoint" [1]=> string(12) "technologies" [2]=> string(5) "India" }
```

Is normal PHP output for this code:

```
$obj = (object) array('qualitypoint', 'technologies', 'India');
var_dump($obj);
```

For more readable format You probably used [Xdebug extension for PHP](http://xdebug.org/).
Check You PHP extensions directory (PHP directory/ext/ on Windows).

If there is not file with name like this:

> php_xdebug-X.X.X-X.X-vcX.dll

[Download one for You PHP version](http://xdebug.org/download.php)

Put it in extensions directory add to PHP configuration (php.ini file) bellow other PHP extensions.

Example:

> zend_extension=PHP_EXTENSIONS_ABSOLUTE_PATH\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll

Restart Apache and var_dump() output will be formatted like this:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  string 'qualitypoint' (length=12)
  string 'technologies' (length=12)
  string 'India' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($obj);
echo '</pre>';
```